# set max results in hibernate not working as per requirement

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

This is my query 
 which is written using HQL. My requirement is as follows.
I've 45 records and I want to fetch 10 records each time. It gives successfully up to 40 records. But from 41-45 records, the query returns empty list.

```
query1 = session
                    .createQuery(
                            "FROM mongo c where "
                                    + "c.ad='555rs5' and "
                                    + "c.cId='44444sf' and "
                                    + "c.langId='59ecc8' and c.date < '"
                                    + tempDate + "' ORDER BY -date")
                    .setMaxResults(10);
```

Anything wrong in my query? Please let me know. 
Regards 
Naresh Veluri

Comment: What do you mean by fetching 10 records each time? Can you show us whole code?

Comment: I'm having 45 records in my data base. I want to fetch each time 10 records by calling the service to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

For Hibernate pagination, next to the `setMaxResults()` method, you also need the `setFirstResult()` method.  Check out [this page.](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/pagination-in-hibernate-with-criteria-api/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there must be a problem in your loop.

As per the K.C. answer you have not set setFirstResult() I dont know how your query fetching next records.Read [Hibernate Doc - setFirstResult()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setFirstResult%28int%29).

```
Query setFirstResult(int firstResult)
Set the first row to retrieve. If not set, rows will be retrieved beginnning from row 0.
Parameters:
firstResult - a row number, numbered from 0
```

Try below code hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
boolean flag = true;
    int firstResult = 0;
    int pageSize = 10;
    int maxResult = 10;

    while(flag) {
        query1 = session.createQuery("FROM mongo c where "
                                        + "c.ad='555rs5' and "
                                        + "c.cId='44444sf' and "
                                        + "c.langId='59ecc8' and c.date < '"
                                        + tempDate + "' ORDER BY -date");
        query1.setFirstResult(firstResult);                 
        query1.setMaxResults(maxResult);
        List<mongo> = query1.list();
        //terminate loop if list is empty or records less than pagesize.
        if(list.isEmpty() || list.size() < (maxResult-firstResult)) {
            flag = false;   
        } else {
            firstResult = firstResult + pageSize;
            maxResult = maxResult + pageSize;
        }   
    }
```